# "azure blue sky" and "azure and blue sky"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction-reduction

I'm wondering if there is a difference in acceptability or naturalness between the following phrases:

> the azure blue sky

> the azure **and** blue sky

Comment: azure and blue together are redundant.

Comment: Redundancy is not the whole story.  "the azure blue sky" is redundant, but it is acceptable. It seems "the azure AND blue sky" is not just redundant; it's also unacceptable.

Comment: Sure, azure blue sky like crimson red dress or blue black skin or sienna orange shoes. However, one should take care in using double adjectives like that. "azure blue" would contrast with something like "navy blue", which, can just be: azure sky and navy gloves.

Answer (score 4):

Most dictionaries define 'azure' as 'bright blue in colour like a cloudless sky', and 'blue' as 'of the colour of the sky without clouds on a bright day, or a darker or lighter type of this', so that 'the azure blue sky' is an example of redundancy (the unnecessary use of more than one word or phrase meaning the same thing). Using 'and' would suggest that the sky had areas that were different shades, and in that case 'blue' would not be a sensible second colour term.

[Azure (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/azure)

[Blue (Cambridge Dictionary)](http://of%20the%20colour%20of%20the%20sky%20without%20clouds%20on%20a%20bright%20day,%20or%20a%20darker%20or%20lighter%20type%20of%20this:)

[Redundancy (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/redundancy)

Comment: "the azure blue sky" is redundant, but is it acceptable?  It seems "the azure AND blue sky" is not just redundant; it's also unacceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Azure is halfway between blue and cyan.  For many people, it would be acceptable to say that azure is a shade of blue and so 'the azure sky' and 'the azure blue sky' would mean the same thing, possibly the latter might be used if the target audience might not be familiar with azure and so the meaning would be clearer from the context.  However, 'the azure and blue sky' suggests that the target audience do know the difference between blue and azure, and that parts of the sky are blue while other parts are azure.

Comment: For people who don't know the difference between "blue" and "azure", do "the azure blue sky" and "the azure **and** blue sky" sound odd?

Comment: I've always thought of _azure_ as a poetical synonym of _blue_, so it sounds nonsensical to me to speak of 'azure _and_ blue'. I don't know where Frog's definition comes from; most dictionaries give similar definitions to Oxford's "bright blue in colour like a cloudless sky".

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_(color)

Comment: @Frog - beware of using Wikipedia, which is crowdsourced, as an authority.

Comment: @KateBunting If "and" is removed, does "the azure blue sky" sound better?

Comment: There are other sources but in this case I submit that common usage is as valid as a dictionary definition.

Comment: “Azure and blue” is odd because azure is a shade of blue.

Comment: To a native english speaker, saying **azure and blue** is like saying **blue and blue**.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=azure+sky%2Cazure+blue+sky%2Cazure+and+blue+sky&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=2) "**Azure and blue sky**" seems to be brand new!

Comment: _The azure sky_ should be sufficient.